# Rails unique column has duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, postgresql

This is the stripped down version of my model .

```
model Paper
  PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER = 1

  validate_uniqueness_of :number, :allow_blank => true
  before_create :alocate_paper_number

  def alocate_paper_number
    return true if self.number.present?
    p_number = Paper.maximum('number') || Paper::PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER 
    self.number = p_number >= Paper::PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER ? p_number+1 : Paper::PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER 
    return true 
  end
end
```

the problem is I have duplicates in the number column .
Any ideas why and how I can fix this without changing the callback . 
I know I could add a uniqueness validation on the database or make a sequence on that column , any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed it ( bare in mind that I couldn't return a validation error )
I've added a uniquness index on the number column ( as mu and Hugo suggested )
and because I couldn't return a validation error in the controller

```
class PaperController < ApplicationController
  def create
    begin
      @paper.save
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      @paper.number = nil
      create
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah there it is. Great work! I'm curious what @Mu thinks about this.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand the order of callbacks :

(-) save

(-) valid

(1) before_validation

(-) validate

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create

(-) create

(5) after_create

(6) after_save

(7) after_commit

So as you can see , it validates the uniquity of your `number` attribute, and then before_create can at its own disposal go against what your validation wants to accomplish.

In regards to a more cleaner architecture, I would put both of these ideas together in your custom model, as it doesn't seem that the number can be choosen by the User. It's just an incrementer, right?

```
def alocate_paper_number
  p_number = Paper.maximum('number') || Paper::PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER 
  self.number = p_number + 1
end
```

That snippet alone, would prevent duplicates, as it always increments upwards ( unless, there's the possibility of the number going the other way that I'm not aware of ), and also there's no reason to return all those trues. Its true enough!

Comment: If you have ` p_number = Paper.maximum('number') || Paper::PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER ` and `self.number = p_number + 1` then make sure you have `PAPER_STARTING_NUMBER = 0` to start the number count with 1.

Comment: There are no other methods modifying the number attribute. If I try adding 2 papers on the same time it gives me duplicated numbers.

Comment: Interesting. Can you unpack that comment "adding 2 papers on the same time"? Can you explain how that happens in your code?

Comment: It doesn't happen in my code , I tried it with another person next to me on the live server , from the same network connection .

Comment: "It is in de docs. validate_uniqueness_of TRIES to make it unique. But if two processes add one record at the same time, they both can contain the same number."
Hugo Logmans seems to be right.

Comment: Ah I see what's happening. Multiple instances are getting saved at the same time. I would stray from everyone's "let the database do it" idea. Only because a database can handle incrementation, but nothing past that. And it sounds like you need logic as well as incrementation. Then the answer to this resides in the code you havn't shown me yet in how you are **saving multiple objects at the same time**.

Comment: "That snippet alone, would prevent duplicates" No, not at all. There's a simple race condition here if two objects are being saved at the same time their `alocate_paper_number` and INSERTs can get interleaved and you get duplicates. You **must** use a unique constraint in the database and be prepared to handle constraint violations. Or better, let the database handle this logic (despite the bizarre and mistaken Rails idea that there shouldn't be any logic in the database).

Comment: Mu is absolutely correct here. I did a bunch of gandering around the nets for some possible solutions but it seems out of my reach. From what I know of your question, I would swim upstream away from the database ( because that's the only place I know to travel ), and see what I could do closer to the logic interaction to *prevent interleaving*.

Comment: ok so I added the uniqueness constraint on the database and added a rescue block on the controller so if the database threw an RecordNotUnique exception I'll send the create method . Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is in de docs. validate_uniqueness_of TRIES to make it unique. But if two processes add one record at the same time, they both can contain the same number.

If you want to guarantee uniqueness, let the database do it. But because that is different for each DB, Rails does not support it by design.

It's explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

With the solution: "To avoid that, you must create a unique index in your database."